# AttributeError: 'BaseQuery' object has no attribute 'is_authenticated'

Tags: python, flask-login

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return Users.query.filter_by(id=user_id)
```

this is my user loader

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST','GET'])
def login():
    msg = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['user']
        password = request.form['pass']
        hashed_password = sha256(password.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
        user = Users.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
        if user:
            if user.hashed_password ==hashed_password:
                login_user(user, remember=True)
                return redirect(url_for('add'))
        else:
            msg = 'incorrect username or password'
    return render_template('login.html',msg=msg)
```

this is my login code i dont know what is wrong here but i'm getting AttributeError: 'BaseQuery' object has no attribute 'is_authenticated' error please help

Comment: What's the _full_ error message?

Comment: i got this error on my browser but there is no error in my terminal where i'm running the server

Comment: @ForceBru there is no full error message this is all i got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change:

```py
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return Users.query.filter_by(id=user_id)
```

to:

```py
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return Users.query.filter_by(id=user_id).first()
```

If you dont use the `first()`, the return type will be a BaseQuery.